# CSS text-align property doesn't account for the width of the text itself

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am trying to make the captions appear centered below the images with the following code :

```
<div style="float:left;width:100px;" class="dataview">
   <div style="width:100px;height:80px;margin:18px;" class="thumb-wrap">
      <img src="{src}" class="icon" />
      <div style="width:100px;text-align:center;">{text}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, the end result is that the text is centered indeed, but placing the beginning of the text in the center of the div, thus making the text appear to the right.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: If you remove margin:18px; text aligned properly in the center. You could add a container for your image and put the margin there.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, you can answer this so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Nice to hear that, not a need to add it as an answer it's a simple trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `margin:18px` and the `width:100px` of the div which contains the text, since its parent div already has `width:100px`:

```
<div style="float:left;width:100px;" class="dataview">
   <div style="width:100px;height:80px;margin:18px;" class="thumb-wrap">
      <img src="{src}" class="icon" />
   <div style="text-align:center;">{text}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to keep the caption center to the image, the width of div consisting the text should have same width as the img. and to make text center apply attribute `align='center'` to the div itself instead of giving css `text-align:center`

```
<img src="{src}" class="icon" />
<div align="center" style="width:width of image;">{text}</div>
```

This will solve your problem